# search process by substring in his register name

Tags: process, elixir

In elixir, I can get the list of processes with their register name with

```
for pid <- Process.list, do: {pid, Process.info(pid, :registered_name)}
[
  {#PID<0.0.0>, {:registered_name, :init}},
  {#PID<0.1.0>, {:registered_name, :erts_code_purger}},
...
```

How can I get only the processes with a substring in their register name?

Example: get only the processes with the substring `MyApp` in their register name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s better to do in a single pass with [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3)

```elixir
Enum.reduce(Process.list(), [], fn(pid), acc ->
  with {:registered_name, name} = reg_name <- Process.info(pid, :registered_name),
       true <- name |> to_string() |> String.contains?("proxy"),
    do: [reg_name | acc],
    else: (_ -> acc)
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Process.list
|> Enum.filter(fn(pid) ->
  {:registered_name, name} = Process.info(pid, :registered_name)
  to_string(name) =~ "MyApp"
end)
|> Enum.map(fn pid -> Process.info(pid, :registered_name) end)
```